# How to import Custom json encoder class into data cataloge

Tags: json, class, kedro

I’ve a df which stores lists in a column. I am saving the df with all columns in json using

config_new:
  type: json.JSONDataSet
  filepath: data/01_raw/new_config.json
  save_args:
    indent: 6

It’s saving all columns ok , except the column with list as string. As in:

“T”:[{
“Col1”: “9”
“Col2”: “[“7”,”9”,”0”,”5”]”
}]

As you can see above col2 list is coming out as string

I am using json encoder class as below in a python script and saving it under src :

import json
 
class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, list):
            return obj.to_json() 
        return super().default(obj)

Updated my config to:

config_new:
  type: json.JSONDataSet
  filepath: data/01_raw/new_config.json
  save_args:
    indent: 6
    cls: custom_encoder.CustomEncoder

However the CustomEncoder is not being identified and shooting error as it can’t call str.

I am not sure on how to import the class to the cataloge

Comment: Please wrap you code in ``` ``` to make it render as code in your post.

Answer (score 0):

So you're on the right track, but you need to subclass the [json.JSONDataSet](https://docs.kedro.org/en/stable/kedro.extras.datasets.json.JSONDataSet.html) and make the changes there, then call the classpath of that custom dataset from your yaml catalog.

https://docs.kedro.org/en/stable/data/how_to_create_a_custom_dataset.html